# Update information of an contact in android

Tags: android

I want to update new information of an contact. I need to update 3 fields: **Name, phone number and company name** of the contact. Here is my code. The problem of my is: the method **does not update any new information**!

Could you show me the reasons why I have the error. And show me how to fix it! Thanks guys!

```
public void editContact(String _id, String name, String phone, String company) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    String where = ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ?" ;
    String[] params = new String[] {_id};

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(where, params)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA, phone)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA, company)
        .build());

    try {
        cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR UPDATE: ", e.getMessage());
    }
    this.finish();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    this.callHomeActivity();
}
```

Comment: are u getting any eroor if yes kindly post the logcat here

Comment: Wait for me about 8 hours. Stackoverflow does not allow me to post answer.

Comment: so u solved the issue?

Comment: I try to update only the name of the contact by using the code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stacks28: This is me - Mr.Pakapun

I try to update only the name of the contact by using the code below. BUT, nothing happends! The name of the contact **is not been updated**. What wrong with the code ?

```
public void editContact(String _id, String name, String phone, String company) {         
    String where =  ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ? AND " +
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ?";
    String[] params = new String[] {_id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(where, params)
            .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            .build());  
    try {           
        cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR UPDATE: ", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```